# Android Toolchain status unknown

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

I have been installing flutter and Android Studio for a few times because I've encountered an unsolved issue. At first, the issue was it did not detect my Android Studio but The Android toolchain had no issue.

[image: Android Studio issue]

After I config my Android Studio and run flutter doctor again, Android Studio was not an issue anymore but turns out Android Toolchain became an issue.

[image: Android toolchain issue]

[image: Android Studio issue2]

My java version: jre1.8.0_291

[image: my java version]

I found some solutions stating that the Obsolete package should be installed in the SDK tools and I already have that
[image: Android SDK Tools Obsolete]

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully solved the issue by editing the environmental variables, set JAVA_HOME values to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291
```

it was previously at the Android Studio jre

Answer (score 0):

If you read the terminal output of the second image carefully, you need to accept the SDK licenses by `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: I've done that and it showed the exception in java